# how to find occurrence of special character using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have an url like this

```
http://foo.com/bar_by_baz.html
```

now I want to extract baz from that URL using a regex. But so far I have managed to write this much only

```
[_]+?\w[^.]+
```

This is giving me

```
_by_baz
```

as output. Now I want to know that how can I select any special character exactly one time or what would be the best approach to solve this using regex ?

I am trying it on python 3.x

Comment: Maybe with a capturing group like `([^\/_]+)\.html`? Or a lookahead: `[^\/_]+(?=\.html)`?

Comment: Please clarify what your environment is, what the regex flavor is, whether lookarounds are supported - what are you doing and why not use `parse_url` like function/method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Here's your regex: `[_]+?([^_.]+)` the group match will return `baz`.. The concept is to isolate underscore and dot from the target match
2. In another case, this works based on capturing only the alphanumerics `[_]+?([A-Za-z0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume from your profile that you are seeking a javascript-friendly solution (you should update your question & tags).

For javascript, you could use this pattern: `/[^_]+(?=\.[a-z]+$)/`

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/nwzbGr/1)  The pattern matches the substring containing no underscores that is followed by a dot then one or more alphabetical characters until the end of the string.

There will be several ways to accomplish your task.  Finding the best/most efficient one can only be achieved if you provide more information about the coding environment/language and a few more sample strings.